# Should I use Qprocess on the stack

Tags: c++, qt

is there any draw back of creating QProcess on the stack,
for something trivial like this

```
void Utils::changeFont()
{
    QString command("book");
    QStringList arguments({"opensans", "10"});
    QProcess fontProcess;
    fontProcess.start(command,arguments);
    fontProcess.waitForFinished();
}
```

i have 10 Utils objects created;

```
Utils a , b , c .....,
```

the all call the `Utils::changeFont()` respectively.

would it be good for the process to be on the stack

i am asking because i have not seen it being used like this on any tutorial.

thanks

Comment: typo? `program` vs `command` ?

Comment: Sure, why not? Qt objects are quite happy in automatic storage (a.k.a. "the stack"), it's all just bytes in the end.

Comment: @Thomas  i was not quite sure as in the qt documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) the example it uses was on the heap, so i thought something may be missing or happen if on the heap

Comment: i added an example of what i need the process for

Comment: I guess it is uncommon to spawn a `QProcess` and then block until it is finished. Suppose you wanted `changeFont` to only start the process and somewhere else you want to see if the process is finished. You cannot do that when its lifetime ends when the method returns. Thats basically what Thomas answer says

Comment: @idclev463035818 i only have that process in that class, if i do it that way it gets deleted becase the parent is on the stack of another class for example `MainWindow::MainWindow(Qwidget *parent){ Utils  s; s.changeFont(); } ` before the change font process is run , the parent class is deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is not related to creating QProcess "on the stack". In fact, stack is a misnomer: what you're really asking is "can I create QProcess as a local variable". Yes, you can, of course!

But such a `QProcess` is useless, because you're not supposed to use the `waitFor` methods - not ever. They are a horrible API. Don't use them: instead, write asynchronous code - i.e. react to the signals indicated by the `QProcess`. In your case, all you need is to delete the object when the process is finished. Thus:

```
// Not a class!!
namespace Utils {
void changeFont()
{
    QString command("book");
    QStringList arguments({"opensans", "10"});
    auto *fontProcess = new QProcess(context);
    QObject::connect(fontProcess, 
                     qOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>(&QProcess::finished),
                     fontProcess, &QProcess::deleteLater);
    fontProcess->start(command,arguments);
}
}
```

Note that `Utils` shouldn't be a class - it's a terrible Java-ism. If you want to group utility functions in a namespace, use a namespace! That's what they are for :) The `changeFont` as presented shouldn't be a method, since it'd just become a static method, and at that point you don't need any state. If you need state, then the class needs to be way more specific than `Utils` - it may be e.g. a class that adapts `QProcess` to your particular uses, but it'd need to be very specific, otherwise you end up with deeply coupled spaghetti code.

In C++ there is almost never a reason to have `Utils` be a class. It's a typical red flag in code reviews. It needs to be a namespace, and if you actually need a class that keeps state, it must be a task-specific class that does one thing and does it well, and has no other functionality.

If you need to e.g. continue whatever work you were in the middle of once the process is finished, you should create a state machine and react to the state transition when the process is finished, and perform subsequent actions there. This way you'll also be explicit about what to do in case of errors. Such issues are plastered over when you write pseudo-synchronous code. If your code has any `waitFor` calls, it's basically broken - you just don't know it yet. Qt has done everyone a grave disservice for providing those pseudosynchronous methods. All they are good for is freezing the UI. Awful stuff if you care one bit about your user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of making it a name space, I just moved from java, so that is why I made it a class

Comment: @EzikeEbuka :) One thing I would suggest as a general approach is to notice similarities between C++ and Java - because we all do that naturally - and then forget about them as soon as you can, because there's very little excellent Java code that would also be excellent C++ code. Even "similar" constructs such as the `new` operator have different uses, and in C++ `new` is mostly an antipattern and belongs in deep library code only, whereas in Java it's normal and necessary. Substantial C++ projects (100kLOC) can have 0 `new`'s in them :)

Answer (score 3):

The example with `new QProcess(parent)` from [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#running-a-process) also assigns a parent `QObject`. You will need that (or another ownership strategy) if the process outlives the scope of the `QProcess`, which the example tacitly assumes.

In your case, you're calling `waitForFinished()` so it's fine if the `QProcess` gets deleted at the end of the function. There is no need for it to live longer.

Comment: i tried to do it like this but the parent object was created on the stack and it would get deleted before the process is run eg. `MainWindow::MainWindow(Qwidget *parent){ Utils  s; s.changeFont(); } `  before it can change the font the utils is deleted

Comment: @EzikeEbuka Why do you create an instance of Utils? `changeFont` should be a static method! It needs no state!

Answer (score 1):

That is ok, actually almost all examples in Qt documentation show creation of the `QProcess` on the stack.

The only drawback is the creation of the object itself. If you need it "rather often" maybe it would be better to create it once.

Comment: i added an example of how i will use the process, would it be better on the stack or on the heap